# Use a linux (Ubuntu) live cd to read a hardware RAID array

Tags: linux, raid, windows-sbs-2008, disaster-recovery, live-cd

I've got a Dell Poweredge 2900 server on it's face. We have had issues with it's PERC 6/i RAID controller over and over this last week. The server's OS is Small Business Server 2008 and it's RAID 5

I'm trying to figure out a way to not boot to the server OS and still see what is on the array (if anything). I've used Ubuntu and Knoppix live CDs in the past to run in live mode then pull files off the system.

Is there a way I can use a linux live CD to read a hardware raid array in that manner? I found some info on software RAID arrays, but none on hardware.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the array is still in tact, and as long as the live CD you're booting has support for the hardware RAID controller and the file system on the RAID then you shouldn't have any problem pulling files off the array in the way you describe - it should just show up as a normal volume.

Support for hardware RAID controllers in any modern Linux is very good, and I believe the PERC is supported by the megaraid driver.

Comment: To follow up, this worked for me. I didn't realize good support for hardware RAID drivers is built into linux distros. For specifics, I used a 32bit Ubuntu 12.04 desktop CD to live boot and was able to access the Dell PERC 6/i controlled raid array.